# Object required error when trying to get End(xlDown) + 1 row

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code that opens first workbook, second workbook, copies a range from the first one and pastes it into the second one. I want to make it select the cell right after the pasted range in the second workbook, but it failes with `Object required` error.

```
Sub tes()
        '**VARIABLES**
        Dim folderPath As String
        folderPath = "Y:\plan_graphs\final\mich_alco_test\files\"
        Dim fileTitle As String
        fileTitle = "5.xlsx"

        Dim dataWorkbook As Workbook
        Set dataWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(folderPath & fileTitle)

        Dim copyRange As Range
        Set copyRange = dataWorkbook.Worksheets("List1").Range("A3:F3", Range("A3").End(xlDown))


        Dim resultWorkbook As Workbook
        Set resultWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open("Y:\plan_graphs\final\mich_alco_test\result.xlsx")

        copyRange.Copy
        resultWorkbook.Worksheets("1").Range("A3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas

        Dim nextRange As Range
        Set nextRange = resultWorkbook.Worksheets("1").Range("A3:F3", _
        resultWorkbook.Worksheets("1").Range("A3").End(xlDown)).Offset(1, 0).Select

End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to first `Set nextRange` without `.Select` and then select with `nextRange.Select`

Comment: Is your worksheet called `1` or are you trying to get the first worksheet?

Comment: Aside from what other people have said (Setting & Selecting in same row).  If `A4` downwards is empty this would return `$A$3:$F$1048576` and then try and move down a row off the bottom of the sheet causing an error.  As you said in your other question though -  _it looks like all my files have no empty cells in A column_ so all should be good... until you reach that one file that doesn't follow the rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't `Set` the range and `Select` it in the same line, try the code section below:

```
copyRange.Copy

With resultWorkbook.Worksheets("1")
    .Range("A3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas

    Dim nextRange As Range
    Set nextRange = .Range("A3").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) ' set the Range first

    nextRange.Select ' <-- select the Range
End With

End Sub
```