# Excel vba select the last line's cell of the selected range

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code that opens first workbook, second workbook, copies a range from the first one and pastes it into the second one. I want to make it select the cell right after the pasted range in the second workbook, but it selects the pasted range + the line after it, while I only need a first free cell in column A to be selected.

```
  Sub tes()
        '**VARIABLES**
        Dim folderPath As String
        folderPath = "Y:\plan_graphs\final\mich_alco_test\files\"
        Dim fileTitle As String
        fileTitle = "5.xlsx"

        Dim dataWorkbook As Workbook
        Set dataWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(folderPath & fileTitle)

        Dim copyRange As Range
        Set copyRange = dataWorkbook.Worksheets("List").Range("A3:F3", Range("A3").End(xlDown))


        Dim resultWorkbook As Workbook
        Set resultWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open("Y:\plan_graphs\final\mich_alco_test\result.xlsx")

        copyRange.Copy
        resultWorkbook.Worksheets("1").Range("A3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas

        'GET THE LAST RANGE
        Dim nextRange As Range
        Set nextRange = resultWorkbook.Worksheets("1").Range("A3:F3", _
        resultWorkbook.Worksheets("1").Range("A3").End(xlDown)).Offset(1, 0)
        nextRange.Select
End Sub
```

How would I do that? I imagine it still has something to do with `xlDown` but can't figure out what.

Comment: Why are you adding an exact dupliacte of a post you opened an hour ago ? I gave you an answer right here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45324117/object-required-error-when-trying-to-get-endxldown-1-row

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object required error when trying to get End(xlDown) + 1 row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45324117/object-required-error-when-trying-to-get-endxldown-1-row)

Comment: @ShaiRado Actually, this seems more like a follow-up question. He seems to be using `xlDown` but needing the standard `xlUp` from the bottom of the spreadsheet trick.

Comment: @JohnColeman ok, so he should at least acknowledge or give some feedback to comments (and answer) given to him in his previous post.

Comment: @ShaiRado Agreed. They should even consider accepting the other answer (which answered the immediate question).

Answer (score 0):

```
   Set nextRange = resultWorkbook.Worksheets("1").Range("A3:F3", _
        resultWorkbook.Worksheets("1").Range("A3").End(xlDown)).Offset(1, 0)
   Set nextRange = resultWorkbook.Worksheets("1").Cells(nextRange.Rows.Count + 3, 1)
```

Solved it for me (I have 3 upper rows that are not included in this selection, so be wary of using the exact number for your case).

Comment: `Set nextRange = nextRange.Cells(nextRange.Rows.Count, 1)` is more robust since it won't fail if later on you decide to add or delete a header row. Magic numbers like "3" are a bit of a red flag.

Comment: @John Coleman, Thanks, but now all my files are very similar in their structure, so I'm using those numbers for now, since I'm wary of adding any new factors (like functions) to the code which might fail or give bugs. Future readers would know to replace my numbers with theirs, I hope.